# Automated Winterization of Interior Pipes

Tags: plumbing

Thinking of trying to automate the winterization of a vacation home - anything to reduce the friction of getting in an out in the winter.

Current process involves a bunch of work in the basement (opening/closing main/drain valves), all relatively easily automatable with some dc-motor controlled ball valves.

However, one piece which is escaping me is how to handle the pressure-relief in the faucets and fixtures throughout the house. Normally, with the water turned off, and the main drains open, we wander the house and open faucets in order to let the water run backwards down to the basement, where it drains out of the house.

A neighbor with a new construction project is building this into the showers at a few strategic points; same concept - DC servo controlled valve, open it for 10 seconds while the drains are open, with the other end of the valve exposed in the shower to give a nice air-gapped drain location.

Without the walls open, this becomes a bit more cumbersome - electrical plugs aren't currently exposed under the cabinets, though we may be able to make modifications.

I had stumbled upon vacuum relief valves ([https://www.amazon.com/WATTS-TUBULAR-LFN36-M1-Relief-2-Inch/dp/B00AUACX5K](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00AUACX5K)) and was curious if these could be used to perform the task at hand?

Alternatively, any other suggestions?

Comment: Interesting concept but seems like a lot of expense and work for a relatively easy chore. You'll probably still have to go around and inspect to make sure everything worked.

Comment: Agreed, between the construction, testing, inspection, maintenance and complexity costs makes this a HUGE net lose.  One place not to be keeping up with the Joneses.  Any engineer should [heed the words of the best engineer](https://youtu.be/mkJ3--2K7yo?t=275) re: plumbing.

Comment: Sorry I found this funny ,,, yes because if you allow a house to get cold enough to freeze internal pipes and you want to spend a bunch on pipes that only have some water in them with no pressure ,,, sorry but I can sell you a system with a professional install that will be cheaper and a guarantee , for less , but the cracks in your dry wall are on you, but the same system is available at 1/2 price with the same guarantee if you keep the house at 50f., true add on the west coast (not mine) and a + better business rating.... if pipes are not full of water they don’t burst even at -20 . Adds ?

Comment: @jack kinda my thoughts as well. We currently have a neighbor who we pay to help us close up the day after we’ve left and the dishwasher has run it’s course. A bit better planning, and we wouldn’t have to run the dish washer. 

But similarly, we have a maid come occasionally, and the water must be either left on or turned on then off again for her usage.

Comment: It’s fun to think about projects like this, but I think this one might be one to scrap. Perhaps a backup remote shutoff and water flow sensor and leave it at that - do the drains manually.